# mysql statement not ordering sum of multiple columns properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the sum of multiple columns and then order by that but I can't seem to get the statement to work properly.

My statement:

```
SELECT *, ('gapple_wins' + 'soup_wins' + 'nodebuff_wins' + 'debuff_wins' + 'archer_wins' + 'classic_wins' + 'axe_wins' + 'hcf_wins' + 'sumo_wins' + 'builduhc_wins') AS total_wins FROM `practice_season_4_data` ORDER BY total_wins DESC LIMIT 20;
```

The statement just returns the first 20 rows in the table, it doesn't sort. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess that gapple_wins, soup_wins, etc. are columns in the table practice_season_4_data, is that right?.   In the result-set, what are you seeing in the total_wins column?  I assume from the tag that you are using mysql, is that right?   How are you submitting this query?  Using the command line or via some application?  If by an application, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select t.* from 
(
    select *, ( your sum here ) as your_alias from your_table 
) as t
order by t.your_alias desc limit 20
```